# JS contact form works in Chrome but not IE or FireFox

Tags: javascript, forms, contacts

I have the following JS for my contact form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contactForm").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!$("#name").val() || !$("#email").val() || !$("#message").val()){
        $("#incompleteMessage").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
    }else{
        $("#sendingMessage").fadeIn();
        $.ajax( {
            url: "php/mail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
            success: function(){
                $("#sendingMessage").fadeOut();
                $("#successMessage").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                $("#name").val( "" );
                $("#email").val( "" );
                $("#message").val( "" );
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
})
```

This JS works fine in Chrome but seems to have issues in FF and IE. It appears that it doesn't enter the success function and just sits on sending message. This is causing multiple form submissions as users keep clicking.

Can anyone see a problem with the JS or suggest a fix?

Comment: Seems fine, are you sure that is the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried assign code to the `fail` method and catch if something goes wrong?

Comment: what is being returned? Might try setting dataType as well as timeout and add error handling for $.ajax

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will have a look. What was the close vote for?